# How to use fit_generator when loading model in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a binary classifier then saved the model as a .h5 file.

Originally I had been using fit_generator to train it.

```
model.fit_generator(
train_generator,
class_weight=class_weights,
steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
epochs=epochs,
validation_data=validation_generator,
validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size,
callbacks=my_callbacks
)
```

When I call load_model and load it again to continue training where I left off, do I use the exact same code for fit_generator, referring to the old train_generator and validation_generator?

The Keras documentation is very sparse on this and there are virtually no examples of using load_model with fit_generator together online.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Why wouldn't you? The load will load the weights. The generator will generate new training samples. Of course it may not start exactly where it finished but as long as shuffled will be fine.